# cmake find_package finds library but does not include it in build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, boost, cmake

Up until now I've included 3 boost libraries using

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread filesystem REQUIRED)
```

Now I've added program_options

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread filesystem program_options REQUIRED)
```

But cmake included only system, thread and filesystem in the resulting Visual Studio 2012 project. That's why I get this error:

```
 2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc110-mt-1_55.lib'
```

Cmake did not throw an error:

```
-- Searching for LibLAS + library
-- Found libLAS version: 1.06.000
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   program_options
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: C:/dev/lib/boost_1_55_0
-- Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: C:/Boost/lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/de ...
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: it should be added to target with target_link_libraries(target_name ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_link_libraries

Comment: Ah, thank you! I did not see that there are 2 CMakeLists.txt files in my project and target_link_libraries was in the other one.